# Powershell adds a new line in the end - how to prevent it?

Tags: powershell, newline

Consider a UTF8 with BOM encoded file, let us call it 1.txt. Next consider the following file:

```
Set-Content 2.txt $(cat 1.txt -Raw) -Encoding UTF8
```

The two files are not equal! Powershell has added an extra new line. Is there a way to prevent it from doing it?

P.S.

I suppose the encoding does not matter here, but in my real life example the files are UTF8 with a BOM, so let us keep it.

**EDIT 1**

Found the following post - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmanning/2007/05/23/powershell-gotcha-of-the-day-set-content-adds-newlines-by-default/

Seems like the answer is to do the following:

```
[io.directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($pwd)
[io.file]::WriteAllText("1.txt", $(cat 15786.sql -Raw), [text.encoding]::UTF8)
```

Is that it? The best way to solve the problem is not to use PowerShell `Set-Content` command? Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Do you have PowerShell v5?

Comment: @Matt Powershell v5 doesn't save from adding newlines with `Set-Content`, I've just tested that. Or is there another catch with PS5 I'm not aware about?

Comment: `Set-Content` is having a switch  `-NoNewline` which should solve your purpose. Could you please try that and see

Answer (score 3):

> Seems like the answer is to do the following....

That certainly used to be the case to avoid this before v5.

Since then the switches for `-NoNewLine` were added to cmdlets like [`Set-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content). So if simplicity is your end game that should work just fine. This change was [lobbied from the Community over the last few years](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/524739/need-nonewline-parameter-on-out-file-add-content-and-set-content).

As eluded to earlier, that switch also works with [`Out-File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and [`Add-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content)